# How to get employee's total hours worked per week relative to a start date on SQL Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datetime-format

I need to get **total hours worked per employee**.

However, instead of getting just the overall total hours, I need to get the **total hours worked per week relative to the employees' start date**.

For context, I have 2 tables:

**1. online_hours Table**
a. employee_id - unique identifier of an employee in the table
b. date - date when an employee clocks in and clocks out
c. in_time - time when an employee clocks in in integer format (e.g. 1589772250)
d. out_time - time when an employee clocks out in integer format (e.g. 1589772288)

**2. employee_created Table**
a. employee_id - unique identifier of an employee in the table
b. created_on - date when an employee joins the company
c. updated_at - date column that shows the most recent date when an update done to the employee_id column

This is my current query:

```
**
WITH online_hour AS**
(
SELECT 
  employee_id,
  
  date,
  
 -- Query to transform in_time and out_time column as timestamps and to get the difference between the two to determine hours worked 
 DATE_DIFF(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(out_time),'Singapore') ,DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(in_time),'Singapore'),HOUR) AS hours_online,
  

FROM 
  online_hours
),


**new_employees AS**
(
SELECT
    employee_id,

    -- Convert created_on/updated_at column to Singapore TIMESTAMP 
    TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S Asia/Singapore', created_on)) AS created_on,

    TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S Asia/Singapore', date_updated)) AS date_updated,

    -- row_num to show only latest date_updated for each employee_id
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY date_updated DESC) AS row_num

FROM
    employee_created
)


SELECT 
  employee_id,
  
  created_on,
  
  SUM(hours_online) AS total_hours
  
  **SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(date, DATE(created_on), DAY) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN hours_online ELSE 0 END) AS total_hours_first_week,
  **
 ** SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(date, DATE(created_on), DAY) BETWEEN 8 AND 14 THEN hours_online ELSE 0 END) AS total_hours_second_week,**
  

FROM 
  online_hour

INNER JOIN 
  employee_created

ON
  online_hour.employee_id =  employee_created.employee_id

GROUP BY 
  employee_id,
  created_on
```

---

My problem are the results I get from the **total_hours_first_week** and **total_hours_second_week** columns. They both output 0.

[image]

What I need is

1. total_hours_first_week - the sum of hours_online (total clocked in hours) within 7 days (using date column) from the created_on column
2. total_hours_second_week - the sum of hours_online (total clocked in hours) from the employee's 8th to 14th day (using date column) from the created_on column

Comment: **1** Please validate the query you have supplied it is full of twin asterisks and it isn't clear what is used and what isn't. i.e. Remove any redundant code.  **2** do you actually need to get "the most recent row" from the employee_created table, or is there only one row for each employee.

Comment: You could check the result of CASE statements inside SUMs, because you have total_hours > 0 for employees, but the condition inside SUM doesn't work as expected. Without access to data it is hard to make assumptions, simplify your query and find a point, where it starts to behave weird.